# Where to put methods?

Tags: .net, methods

I have data objects with methods for loading, saving, updating data. Then I have objects for more complex manipulation of this data, and to this end they require elaborated data from the data object.

So I started adding methods to the data object for answering specific questions which the manipulating objects need to know. The manipulating objects only have methods strictly related to manipulation or to some feature while info on the data object is elaborated by it. The manipulating objects asks and the manipulated object responds. That is how I imagined it at first. Then I realised they could as well be methods of the manipulating objects or extension methods.

I feel the data object is starting to have too many methods related to specific features, and more are to come. Since these features are mainly managed by the manipulating objects, they could be moved and distributed between them. The problem is some of these methods are used by different manipulating objects and manipulating objects are full enough of methods which are specifically related to manipulation. So another option would be to implement them as static extension methods and place them in the namespace where such works are carried out (so they are only visible from the working area but can be called by other objects if need be).

The question is where to put methods that:

- give info elaborated from data object info (public info), without any kind of manipulation
- are for the specific use of one or a few other objects for specific features (manipulation mainly, but also queries and presentation)
- (some use helper business objects, some only depend on the data object and require nothing else)

Should they belong to:

- the data object
- the manipulating objects
- to a static helper class in business namespace ?

I suppose the answer depends a lot on which methods we are talking about, on the design of the application, etc. so I understand specific advice may be difficult to give, but I would appreciate any tips which help me make a decision in this and other cases.

In a nutshell:

**What are the criteria or what questions should I ask myself in order to choose where to put methods?**

Comment: I believe you're really asking about OO design.  If so, that's a biiiigggg topic.  SUGGESTION: Google for ["S.O.L.I.D. Programming Principles"](http://www.dofactory.com/topic/1046/design-patterns-vs-design-principles-solid.aspx).  Or get a copy of the book [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#, Martin & Martin](http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Principles-Patterns-Practices-C/dp/0131857258/)

Comment: @paulsm4 Thank you. Yes you are right. I am thinking about how to make my question more specific, but I feel it will also relate to OO design principles.

Comment: Just an opinion.  An object that manipulates and does not save data should be a static method.  You comment on specific use by one or a few leads me to believe you may have base data objects and need to add specific data objects that inherit.  As for where to put methods elaborated from data object - the answer not a methods at all - a public property on the data object.

Comment: @Blam Do you mean that if methods don't modify the object's data, they don't fit in that object but in static methods? Or, as user1494... said, in another class, like InfoFoo or FooInspector?

Comment: It was just an opinion. Take it or leave it.  Meant exactly what I said.  If the class has no data itself then it is better as static method.

Comment: @Blam, I take it, it all adds to the brainstorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal experience, putting a single responsibility/functionality/feature etc... per object (or class) works extremelyl well.

That's why I'd suggest you: 
Create 1 class for each type of data object you need to handle.
    Examples: DataObjectA, DataObjectB
Create 1 class for each operation you need to do over those data objects (or maybe a class for each pair operation x data object type, depending on how similar they are).
    Examples: DataObjectLoader, DataObjectASaver, DataObjectAUpdater and maybe DataObjectALoader and DataObjectBLoader too.
Create 1 class for each more complex manipulation of that data:
    Examples: DataObjectAComplexThing

If the elaborated data has required to do the Complex Thing has "sense" by itelf, and it's a problem you recognize in the domain, and you can easily name, you should create a class for that too:
    Examples: ObtainDataRequiredForComplexThing

The DataObject should only answer the basic queries needed to "define" exactly what that object is... All the additional stuff should be on either ObtainDataRequiredForComplexThing or DataObjectAComplexThing kind of calsses.

My criteria to decide where to put thing is... Thins should only have the methods, fields, etc.. that are strictly neccesary... Anything that you can take away, you should take it away and put it somewhere else (in another class, or whatever [within reason of course]).
If you can solve a problem using a single class, or by using more than one class, and each of those smaller classes have "sense" by themselves, and you can recognize that problems in the domain, and you can give them a proper name... You should use the multiple smaller classes...
Composing objects (or classes) it's a lot more easiser than spliting them. So whenever you have the chance, you almost always split them into smaller constructing blocks....

Most people say that you should create Objects (or classes) for each Noun in the Domain, and Methods for each Verb in the Domain....
In my experience it's a better idea to create Objects for each Noun, and Objects for each Verb to.
Example: new SomeVerbThatRepresentsDoingSoething(aDataObject).ExecuteThisVerb(); //to implement doing that Verb

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I could use smaller Doer classes. As for ObtainDataRequiredForComplexThing, if not holding data itself, would make more sense as static, as @Blam suggested?

Comment: Object & Classes aren't just for holding data. You can use them to organize the knowledge, and to compose it from little parts... If you implement things like ObtainDataRequiredForComplexThing as classes you can do a lot of interesting things and produce cleaner and better code, if you know what you are doing. Check this: http://blogs.southworks.net/dgeffner/2011/08/08/object-oriented-algorithms/.

Comment: Again thanks. I have refactored some things into new Doer classes and it does look cleaner.